# use variable inside of object for other variable

Tags: javascript, json

```js
module.exports = {
    bot: {
        version: "Pre-Alpha",
        displayType: "WATCHING",
        displayGame: `Looking for targets...           | Version: ${version}`
    },
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way that i could use the variable "version" inside of displayGame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable before assigning to `exports` so you can refer to it in both places.

```
let version = "Pre-Alpha";

module.exports = {
    bot: {
        version: version,
        displayType: "WATCHING",
        displayGame: `Looking for targets...           | Version: ${version}`
    },
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a function and pass the version to it. Then return the Object

```
module.exports = {
    bot(version) {
        return {
            version: version,
            displayType: 'WATCHING',
            displayGame: `Looking for targets...           | Version: ${version}`,
        };
    },
};
```